# how to check if the form has been refreshed/reloaded/closed in js

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i know this question was asked before but i can't get this to work.

I have a .aspx which contains a function on the onunload body tag. This should refresh the parent page after the child page was closed.

At this point, i need to know if the page was refreshed/reloaded, because this logic will trigger the function call everytime and close my "child" page.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshparent(){
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

And this is what i want to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshparent(){
      if(page.wasclosed){
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
      }else{
   //do nothing
      }
    }
    </script>
```

this a part of is my aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #d6eceb" onunload="refreshparent()">
```

Comment: What was wrong with the answer that was provided yesterday?

Comment: Also im not very good at js, please explain to me how to make this work as detailed as possible, thanks!

Comment: Hello Emiel, i answered yesterdays post explaining it is adding the "#loaded" at the first time page is loaded, not when reloaded.

Comment: Oh okay. What do you mean with *parent page* and *child page*? `window.opener` is not something that is on the `window` object, did you add it? You should avoid using the [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event#usage_notes) event.

Comment: This also looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Try explaining what is is you're trying to build, instead of finding a solution for your solution.

Comment: let me explain, i have a form (parent page) which calls a js function named CallForm, this is the code:

<script type ="text/javascript">

        function CallForm( value ) {

            if (value == "1") {
                 window.open(URI, 'mywindow', 'toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');  
            }
                            
           
                    

                }

Comment: So, after the "child" page was opened, and the users makes all the changes he want's to, i need to catch the event that closes the window

Comment: only and only when child page is closed, not refrehsed/reloaded, so then i run the refresh parent logic

Comment: Also, i dont know what "adding to window object" means, im kinda new on programming

Comment: I see what you mean. Does the URL of the *child* page have the same origin as the *parent* page and can you control the JavaScript of the child page. This is important to know if you the child page can tell the parent page if it is going to close.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by origin of the URL, this is the url of the parent 
(i'm working locally)=
localhost:8081/saes/SUR/Folders/frmParent.aspx?

this is the url of the child 
ocalhost:8081/saes/SUR/DifferentFolder/frmChild.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

A way to communicate between multiple tabs or windows (that have the some origin, e.g. `https://yourdomain.com/`) is with the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API). With it, you can open communications between the tabs and send data back and forth.

This might be helpful in your case to have the child page tell the parent window that it is going to close. Use the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event to trigger sending a message *before* the child window is closed.

Apply the following scripts to their respective files.

#### Script for your *parent* window.

This script opens a broadcast channel and listens for any incoming messages. Whenever the message is a string equal to `'refresh'`, then the page will reload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const channelName = 'form-closing-channel';
  const channel = new BroadcastChannel(channelName);

  channel.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
    if (data === 'refresh') {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### Script for your *child* window.

This script only sends a message to other open parent window(s) just before it is going to close. The message that is sent will be `'refresh'`, which should trigger the reload in the parent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const channelName = 'form-closing-channel';
  const channel = new BroadcastChannel(channelName);

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    channel.postMessage('refresh');
  });
</script>
```

**Important**
Do note that **all** parent windows will respond to the received message. E.g. you have 3 open parent windows and 1 open child, closing the child will send `'refresh'` to all of the parent windows and they will all reload.

Comment: Thanks for the help Emiel, but this would be running every time child page is refreshed, not closed, am i right?

Comment: It will be triggered in both cases. Reloads / refreshes count as a close and open.

Comment: @PabloBongiolatti I'm curious to learn if this solved your issue.

Comment: Hi emiel thanks for asking, yes i could, so: i removed the onunload body tag of the child form, and when the user clicks on the final check of the form (after commiting the changes to the DB ) i call a script like this=

function func(){
window.opener.bindgrid;
}

Comment: and then, i close the popup (child form) calling a window.close()

Comment: and added a function on parent page called bindgrid which calls a __dopostback wich reloads the form

Comment: i think i forgot to mention that the parent page reload was meant to reload a gridview with different data from another query, thanks for the help! @emiel-zuurbier

Comment: Any detail to the question is welcome ;). Good to hear that you figured something out. I'll delete the answer shortly as it doesn't provide a suitable answer for the question.